# Setting a tag filter in review often returns no results

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, review-queues, first-post-review

### Bug

When a review queue filter is re-applied without changes, no review tasks are returned.

### Steps to Reproduce

- Select a review queue.
- Apply a filter tag (I used `python`, and also used multiple tags `python` `matplotlib`).

  - Result: Filtered review queue tasks are returned.
- Open filter and select Apply again (without changing filter).

  - Result:

  > There are no items for you to review, matching the filter "[python]".

This is reproducible on First Questions, First Answers (previously First Posts) and Late Answers. I would expect that the same tasks would be returned as the query is using the same filter.

Comment: Yeah, this does seem to happen with Late Answers. It doesn't seem to happen with the Reopen queue though, which has a filter option as well.

Comment: Wasn't there a recent meta question about this (also about filters)? Or at least related? Or on MSE?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I couldn't find anything before posting, but that doesn't mean that it's not there.

Comment: Just came across this bug as well. Say the question to be reviewed is tagged `python` and you filter by `python`, would one expect the system to keep the question in place or retrieve a new one? What appears to be happening is that the first time filter works for that where results are returned and then does not thereafter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that this is now resolved. Please let me know if you are still running into it.