# I got the "Access review queues" privilege. How can I filter on known programming languages only?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, reputation

I can now review other peoples' post. How can I filter what is proposed to me?

I don't really know Python, PHP, etc... But I can verify other known programming languages. Is there a way to filter the post I can review to be more useful?

Maybe using the tag I set within my profile...

I want to participate, but I would feel more comfortable to start with something I know. It could be a checkbox somewhere or just for the first 50 reviews.

I know it's not always about code, but this can help people get better feedback instead of a downvote for code snippet that is wrong.

I just want to make it easier for everyone. I know I can skip...

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding. For most review queues, there's a big ["Filter" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE9ch.gif) which allows you to specify up to 3 tags which the question must include (or the question on which the answer was posted must include).  Is that button missing for you (doesn't exist in Triage)? Is it that only up to 3 tags is insufficient for your filtering desires (even if you have to use a separate tab to have other/additional tags)?

Comment: Note that the filter exists, but it often [returns no results due to a bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410654/6083675).

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicates: [Easy close review queue filtering interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202261/easy-close-review-queue-filtering-interface/231856#231856) [First preference to the questions in the Close Vote RQ under a tag where the user is familiar with that tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234868/first-preference-to-the-questions-in-the-close-vote-rq-under-a-tag-where-the-use/234879#234879)

Comment: What known programming languages? [Ruby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLmocggLMj4&t=6m17s)?

Comment: @Makyen I don't *do* Triage very much but I just went to the queue and can confirm: **The big "Filter" button is missing!** (It's there for all the other queues.) [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VT0D.png)

Comment: ... se also [related post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297317/10871073)

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, what I was attempting to communicate was that the button is, or at least should be, in all the queues which the OP can access, except Triage (i.e. the OP didn't need to bother looking for it in the Triage queue, because it isn't there).